# Read video frame by frame and show picture each frame by using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-capture, video-processing

I am newly working with Matlab. Now, I'm doing a small project about image processing. I want to read a video frame by frame and find intensity of each frame. Help me,please

```
Read video code :
```

** It can't use hasFrames **
error : Undefined function 'hasFrame' for input arguments of type 'VideoReader'.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post your code that you used to encounter this error.  It is impossible to determine what is wrong based on that error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>There is no such thing as `hasFrames` in MATLAB for the `VideoReader` class.</s>

There is a function called `hasFrame` in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.hasframe.html, but it only exists as of `R2014b`.  The documentation for `R2014b` was just released last week, and I prematurely said that there wasn't a function called `hasFrame` because I have never seen it with the `VideoReader` class that I am used to.  I currently use `R2013a`.  Check out this thread from MathWorks for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157477-unable-to-read-and-playback-movie-file

This error is probably happening because you don't have the latest version of MATLAB.  If you want to read a frame from the video file using the `VideoReader` class, use the `readFrame` function after you read in the video from file: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.readframe.html.  Don't use `hasFrame`.  You can always check to see if the matrix that is returned from `readFrame` is empty which could symbolize whether your video has a frame available or not.

Calling `readFrame` will provide you a video frame where you can do your analysis.  You call it each time to grab the next frame in the video.

Good luck!

Comment: I think there is a method called [`hasFrame`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.hasframe.html).

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - I don't have `hasFrame` on my MATLAB distribution.  It only exists as of `R2014b`.  I'll modify my post, but I couldn't find this function on my distribution of MATLAB... and this is most likely what is happening with the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, rayryeng and Parag S. Chandakkar